# Pardot Prospect sync when connecting to a new SFDC org

Tags: migration, pardot, data-migration, sync

in a new project we have a bit of a tricky migration issue I never faced before, described in the following:

**The context:**
The customer moved his Service Cloud license to a reseller. Due to this we have to migrate the customer to a completely new org where contacts and leads will be uploaded with new salesforce Ids.
Somehow the connected Pardot instance was forgotten in all this.

**The issue:** 
After checking the documentation and various threads here it seems that Prospect Ids are fixed (to the old orgs SF Ids now) and there's no way to update those with either API or export/import procedures.

**The questions:**

- Has anyone here ever done or tried anything like this?
- If yes, is there a procedure we should follow?
- Is there a chance that Pardot still tries to find matching Salesforce records based on email even if it already has a Prospect Id from the old org?

Due to time pressure I wasn't able to check this specific type of (re)sync behaviour in a test environment, yet. 
As soon as I get to doing this and have relevant findings I will share those here to contribute back.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I will give you a short and direct answer to this.(I was only able to find it after couple of days research).

The easiest way to overcome this is

1. Do not setup existing Pardot instance with new SF org (ie. do not setup the connector with new SF)
2. Add all the prospects in Pardot to a specific list and name it accordingly
3. Get in touch with Pardot support and inform them that you are migrating and need to avoid creating duplicates.
4. Share the list created (in step 2) with Pardot Support and ask them to delete  CRM Id's(Pardot wont disable AMPSEA but support can clear out the prospect CRM ids for you)
5. Once the CRM ID's are cleared out in Pardot. Setup the new SF connector and choose match with email-ids as sync behaviour
6. Perform a sanity check to see that duplicates are not created and ask Pardot support for full sync on your pardot
7. Now your existing Pardot contacts will be in sync with respective prospects in SF (matched with email ids)

The above steps will help you connect existing Pardot instance with new SF org without creating duplicate records.

There is another way to sync up SF and Pardot instances but with some data loss. Lemme know if anyone wants to discuss it in detail.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the update and sharing the process! The really important part to me is that support is able to clear out the CRM id's. This was the point where I got stuck with my original idea

Comment: @StephandePaly I am facing a similar issue. Was support able to help you out? Here is my issue: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/271394/pardot-sync-issue

Comment: My situation turned out different in the end. Your linked issue sounds like it could be addressed by Sankets answer. You should give it a go

Comment: BTW: if does work out for you please provide an answer to your own question with a reference to Sankets answer in this thread and mark it as solved so that others can follow the connection.

Comment: I raised a case with Salesforce and they asked me create a static list of records which needs to be corrected. Once I gave them the list, they cleared out the CRM Ids for these records.