# Pardot Campaign and user sync when connecting to a new SFDC org

Tags: user, single-sign-on, campaign, migration, pardot

We are going to merge our Salesforce org with other org. We need to connect our Pardot to new org.
I had a question about CRM id which was answered clearly below by @Sanket Nagure. Thanks for that guys!
[Pardot Prospect sync when connecting to a new SFDC org](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/227242/pardot-prospect-sync-when-connecting-to-a-new-sfdc-org/347740#347740)

Is it the same process for campaigns? In our org Pardot campaign is connected to Salesforce so in new org we need to sync our historic campaigns in new org as well.

My other question is about users. Considering SSO for Pardot to login from Salesforce how should users be created and connected to historic Prospects? we don't have lead or contact in Salesforce for all prospects in Pardot )?
Thanks